# Refactoring - Just code SqlParameterCollection.Add Method is obsolete

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

I'm currently refactoring the code using the tool "Just code" which displayed one of the warnings as:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add(string,object) is obsolete.

Also from MSDN I found that:

> SqlParameterCollection.Add Method (String, Object).
>
> Note: This API is now obsolete.

I was wondering whether I should refactor this code :

```
SqlCommand cmdGetIds= oConn.CreateCommand();
cmdGetIds.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdGetIds.CommandText = "GetEmployeeId_sp";
cmdGetIds.Connection = oConn;

cmdGetIds.Parameters.Add("@User", "ADMIN");
```

Comment: Just found from msdn website to use  : AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object value)

Answer (score 0):

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add(string,object) is
>   obsolete.
>   Warning   1   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add(string,
>   object)' is obsolete: 'Add(String parameterName, Object value) has
>   been deprecated.  Use AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object
>   value).  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202'

If you see this problem, you can solve it like this:

```
SqlCommand cmdGetIds= oConn.CreateCommand();
cmdGetIds.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdGetIds.CommandText = "GetEmployeeId_sp";
cmdGetIds.Connection = oConn;
cmdGetIds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", "ADMIN");
```